# Codeigniter Index.php in HTTPS URL

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl, https, indexing

I'm having an issue with CodeIgniter and htaccess.

When I access to my website in http or in localhost, I can access to mysite.ext/**controller/view** , like **admin/login**, for example.

But when I access to my website with HTTPS before, it's sending a 404 error, so I have to write mysite.ext/*index.php*/**controller/vie**w, and it works.

The problem is I don't want the index.php and when I try solutions I found on the internet, it removes index.php sometime, but I can only access to the **/index/** controller, not the admin and the other ones.

I tried this solution here :
[codeigniter + not index.php with https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231482/codeigniter-not-index-php-with-https)

It removes the index.php, which is the bootstrap, and the **controller/view** **index/firstpage** works, but not the other controllers.

PS : the HTTPS URL is different than the HTTP URL. HTTP URL takes to the server, but the HTTPS is provided by my hoster (so, https:// ovh....blabla../mywebsite/)

I would like to understand why it's not working and find how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specailly do configuration for codeIgniter setup in https url. First you remove $config['base_url] from your config file and put ''(blank) in your $config['index'] attribute ..

you can set your .htaccess file like..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
      ErrorDocument 404 index.php
  </IfModule>
```

Above code is remove index.php from url.